# ListView with LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

I am kinda new to the android programming and i would like to implement a ListView which items are a custom LinearLayout, programmatically.
I have tried something like

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.list_view);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
lv.addView(ll);
```

But it crashes.
Can anyone give me an example of how this should be done?
Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are looking for custom adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<E>
{
    //List of Events
    private ArrayList<E> myList;

    /*
     * Creates the Adapter for the list
     */
    public MyArrayAdapter (Context context,  int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<E> list)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        myList= list;
    }

    /**
     * inflate view for each row
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {           
        View v = convertView;
        // if the given channel row view is not being updated
        if (v == null) 
        {
            // inflate you linear 
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.channel_list_row, null,false);
        }


        // edit view here, as shown below
        TextView topTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
                    ...

        // return the view for the given position
        return v;           
    }
}
```

And in main code

```
 // create the  array adapter
 myArrayAdapter = new MyChannelAdapter(Activity Cntext, Custom row layout, lList);
 // bind the array adapter to the list view
 ListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must implement a custom `Adapter` for your ListView. An `Adapter` is like a row in the list.
Please take a look at this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html or to this similar question: [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Answer (score 0):

please find..
[ListView good tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)